# Xpath creation for Selenium for clicking a dropdown menu

Tags: python, css, selenium

I m trying to select a dropdown arrow menu after Status.

I'm trying to build a Xpath to click this :

```
<a href="javascript:" class="btn btn3d selectionbtn" style="top:0px; left:136px; width:21px; height:21px;">
```

Xpath = `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[id="WIN_3_7"]/div/a').click()`

But it says that the

> Unable to locate an element

[image]

Below is the HTML snippet of the above image.

```html
<div id="WIN_3_7" arid="7" artype="EnumSel" ardbn="Status" arlbox="0,4,104,17" class="df arfid7 ardbnStatus EnumSel" style="z-index:1928;top:173px; left:705px; width:262px; height:21px;" arwindowid="3">
<label id="label7" class="label f9" for="x-arid_WIN_3_7" style="top:4px; left:0px; width:104px; height:17px;">Status*</label><div class="selection" style="top:0px; left:105px; width:157px; height:21px;" arselmenu="[{v:&quot;Assigned&quot;},{v:&quot;Pending&quot;},{v:&quot;Waiting Approval&quot;},{v:&quot;Planning&quot;},{v:&quot;In Progress&quot;},{v:&quot;Completed&quot;},{v:&quot;Rejected&quot;},{v:&quot;Cancelled&quot;,l:&quot;Canceled&quot;},{v:&quot;Closed&quot;}]">
<input id="arid_WIN_3_7" type="text" class="text " readonly="" style="top:0px; left:0px; width:136px; height:21px;" title="Assigned">
<a href="javascript:" class="btn btn3d selectionbtn" style="top:0px; left:136px; width:21px; height:21px;">
<img class="btnimg" src="../../../../resources/images/mt_sprites.gif" alt="">
</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To click and expand the dropdown menu you can use the following line of code :

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@id="WIN_3_7"]/div[@class='selection']/a[@class='btn btn3d selectionbtn']/img[@class='btnimg']"))).click()
```

---

### Update

As an alternative you can also try to `click()` on the `<input>` tag and expand the dropdown menu as follows :

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='text' and @id='arid_WIN_3_7']"))).click()
```

Comment: Got an error saying that `is not clickable at point (986 , 315) other element would receive the click.` 

Thats why i went with Actionchains to do this 

`drop = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(`driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[id="WIN_3_7"]/div/a'))).click() 
AC.move_to_element(drop).click().perform()

Comment: @ManojAsManu Checkout my answer update and let me know the status

Comment: @DebanjanB : Xpath that you are using arid_WIN_3_7 is dynamic , and should be avoided !

Comment: @cruisepandey Do you see any potential issue with dynamic xpath?

Comment: @DebanjanB : Yes it might not just work on different systems, different browsers  !

Comment: it didn't work , gives me timeoutexception. @DebanjanB. i tried element_to_clickable with other Xpath's but all the Xpath's gave me timeoutexceptions.